# epsilon delta proofs notation question

Tags: real-analysis, notation

If I want to say let $\delta$ be less than $\epsilon/6$ or $1$, whichever is smaller do I denote it as

$\delta< \min\{\epsilon/6,1\}$ or $\delta< \min(\epsilon/6,1)$??

Comment: The latter looks like the min of an open interval of reals, which doesn't have a min. So I'd go with the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally write $\delta < \min \{ \epsilon/6 , 1 \}$ which makes it immediately clear what you mean.

I've never seen anyone using  $\delta < \min(\epsilon /6 ,1 )$ for expressing this, because $\{ \}$ normally denotes a set and $()$ denotes a touple (ordered). In the case of $\min$ it does not make sence to use an ordered structure as argument anyways.

Comment: I forgot to say min on mine. so which one is it, is it {} or ()??????????

Comment: It is clearly $\{\}$, as I said, I've never seen anyone using anything else.

Comment: the person above is using delta<min(  ) though.

Comment: Yes and I do not know anyone would do that, I think he just wanted to point out that you have to use $\min$ and didn't care about the parenthesis.

Comment: Yes, didn't care about parenthesis. However, BOTH are ok.

Answer (score 2):

It is usually like this:
$$\delta\ <\ \min(\varepsilon/6,\,1)\,.$$
If you want, $\min$ is a *function* in two (or more) variables -- we can also call it an *operation*. 
On the other hand, the notation $\min S$ is also valid where $S$ denotes a set (of any ordered things).

Comment: then how come flawr is saying with ( )?

Comment: To be honest, I use both interchangably. The way I think of this is like so: $ \min\{\}$ for minimum of a set, $ \min(x,y)$ to think of minimum as a function which takes a tuple $(x,y)$ and returns the minimum of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Meanwhile you changed the question. I thought you were asking about the keyword 'min'